# Circles on kitchen cabinets

Tags: kitchens, cabinets

My cabinets are less than three years old and I noticed all of these blue circles this morning. The cabinets are white so these are pretty noticeable. Is this showing through the finish somehow? Is there any way to fix this?[image]

[image]

Comment: Have you tried rubbing them with a damp cloth?  Is it all the cabinets or just a narrow section?  Could someone have placed something on or against the surface to do something?

Comment: That was my first thought that it was an imprint. Tried removing it with a wet cloth and even a cabinet spray. This is fairly high up, about eye level. I do not see it on other cabinets as of now. The other reason I think it is showing through is that it is in one of the grooves, which would be difficult for an imprint or something leaning on it.

Comment: Do you think they have been there for a while and you just noticed them now, or did they suddenly appear?

Comment: What type of wood? Are these premade? I agree with the bubble wrap. I am wondering if a “stamp” was on the wood prior to paint and now the paint allows the stamp to show. I ran into this with some big brand off the shelf cabinets as they were cheaper than we could get the wood for. The family that purchased the house noticed several months later and scrubbing made it worse. It took another coat of enamel to hide it but with the light just right you could still see the stamps.

Answer (score 15):

This pattern looks like bubble wrap.

[image: bubble wrap packaging]

As such, it has probably been present since the cabinets were installed and the spot you're seeing may have been a pressure point where the wrap was strapped or secured to hold the cabinet in place for transport. It's hard to tell whether the white surface of the cabinets has another color bleeding through from behind, the white finish is damaged/thinned by contact with the bubble wrap, or some color from a non-transparent bubble wrap has leeched into the white finish.

Anyway, try wiping with cloth with a gentle soap solution and see if it comes off easily. If it does not, you could try an abrasive sponge (Magic Eraser) or harsher soaps and chemicals. Try these on a hidden or not noticeable section first. If the problem gets worse instead of better, it may be a finish below the white that's bleeding through a thin white layer (that's getting thinner as you scrub), and you'll probably need to refinish the cabinets. Hopefully it's just on the surface and you can scrub it away and be done.

Comment: Good thought, it does look like bubble wrap. Unfortunately I tried a magic eraser as well and that didn't seem to do anything.

Comment: Good catch on the bubble wrap. I thought it looked like a shoe print until I read that it was above eye level. Of course, if there's a kid in the house playing ninja...

Comment: My first thought was shoeprint also, until I read that these aren't newly-installed cabinets. I figured it had been stepped on on the floor.

Comment: Looking at the relief there is a circle so probably correct. I was thinking a stamp but looking closer noticed it on the beveled edge, the stamps were only on the flat sections+

Comment: @FredricShope If someone had stepped on it like that they probably would have broken the cabinet.

Comment: it is bubble wrap's plasticizers leaching into the cabinet finish. You'll need to a use a solvent that works on the off-gassed chemicals to remove it. Try long slow wet wiping with IPA, naptha, acetone in that order- one should do the trick.